# Laravel 5.1 Singleton Always New Instance

Tags: php, singleton, laravel-5.1

Facing issues with Laravel's IoC and Singleton.

I have the following singleton class:

```
class ConcreteClass
{
    function __construct() {Log::info('I iz created...');}
}
```

And the following service provider:

```
class ConcreteClassServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('ConcreteClass', function () {
            return new ConcreteClass();
        });
    }
}
```

However with every `App::make('ConcreteClass')`, `public function __construct(ConcreteClass $concrete)` in a single request will cause the log to have a `I iz created...` which makes it highly doubtful the singleton thing works in Laravel. I am most probably wrong with the configuration. Please help me with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you use your instance but it could be a namespace thing. When I tried instantiating my singleton by specifying the full path, for example:

```
@inject('foo', 'App\.....\FooSingleton');
```

It did not work.

I had to do it by only specifying the name without the path, i.e:

```
@inject('foo', 'FooSingleton');
```

Why? I don't know. It's still a mystery to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I gave it a try with the namespace you have suggested and it worked, partially. Apparently using App::make('SingletonNameAsPerServiceProvider'); works. Partially work because when it's accessed using App::make it works, or using @inject in a blade template it works. But some how when requesting it via another class it seems like it doesn't get initiated as a singleton. But it works in most of the case. Will mark this as the answer :)